# python client recv only reciving on exit inside BGE

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, freeze, recv

using python 3, I'm trying to send a file from a server to a client as soon as the client connects to the server, problem is that the client do only continue from recv when I close it (when the connection is closed)

I'm running the client in blender game engine, the client is running until it gets to recv, then it just stops, until i exit the game engine, then I can see that the console is receiving the bytes expected.

from other threads I have read that this might be bco the recv never gets an end, that's why I added "\n\r" to the end of my bytearray that the server is sending. but still, the client just stops at recv until I exit the application.

in the code below I'm only sending the first 6 bytes, these are to tell the client the size of the file. after this i intend to send data of the file on the same connection.

what am I doing wrong here?

**client:**

```
import socket
import threading
def TcpConnection():
    TCPsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    TCPsocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    server_address = ('localhost', 1338)
    TCPsocket.connect(server_address)
    print("TCP Socket open!, starting thread!")
    ServerResponse = threading.Thread(target=TcpReciveMessageThread,args=(TCPsocket,))
    ServerResponse.daemon = True
    ServerResponse.start()
def TcpReciveMessageThread(Sock):
    print("Tcp thread running!")
    size = Sock.recv(6)#Sock.MSG_WAITALL
    print("Recived data", size)
    Sock.close()
```

**Server:**

```
import threading
import socket
import os

def StartTcpSocket():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(('localhost', 1338))
    server_socket.listen(10)
    while 1:
        connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        Response = threading.Thread(target=StartTcpClientThread,args=(connection,))
        Response.daemon = True  # thread dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
        Response.start()
def StartTcpClientThread(socket):
    print("Sending data")
    length = 42
    l1 = ToByts(length)
    socket.send(l1)
    #loop that sends the file goes here
    print("Data sent")
    #socket.close()
def ToByts(Size):
    byt_res = (Size).to_bytes(4,byteorder='big')
    result = bytearray()
    for r in byt_res:
        result.append(r)
    t = bytearray("\r\n","utf-8")
    for b in t:
        result.append(b)
    return result
MessageListener = threading.Thread(target=StartTcpSocket)
MessageListener.daemon = True  # thread dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
MessageListener.start()
while 1:
    pass
```

if the problem is that the client don't find a end of the stream, then how can solve this without closing the connection, as I intend to send the file on the same connection.

Update #1:
to clarify, the print in the client that say "recived" is printed first when I exit the ge (the client is closing). The loop that sends the file and recives it where left out of the question as they are not the problem. the problem still occurs without them, client freeze at recv until it is closed.

Update #2:
here are a image of what my consoles are printing when i run the server and client:
[image]
as you can see it is never printing the "Recived" print
when i exit the blender game engine, I get this output:
[image]
now, when the engine and the server script is exited/closed/finished i get the data printed. so recv is probably pausing the thread until the socket is closed, why are it doing this? and how can i get my data (and the print) before the socket is closing? This also happens if I set

```
ServerResponse.daemon = False
```

[here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/7ld5581nxl4j9h2/networkTest.blend) are a .blend (on mediafire) of the client, the server running on python 3 (pypy). I'm using blender 2.78a

Update #3:
I tested and verified that the problem is the same on windows 10 and linux mint. I also made a Video showing the problem:

In the video you can see how I only receive data from the server when i exit blender ge. After some research I besinning to suspect that the problem is related to python threading not playing well with the bge.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5l9YGIoDYA

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow/help/mcve).  The code as presented isn't runnable (missing imports) and the important part of sending and receiving the file is missing.  If the imports are added this code sends the six bytes correctly, although `sendall` would be better to use.  The client is set as a daemon and the main code immediately exits after starting the thread...killing it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen sry for the missing imports, added them to the question. The sending and reciving part aren't the problem, that's why I left them out. Even when the client isen't a deamon and the server is using sendall the result is the same.

Comment: Please run what you post.  It is not reproducible.  `PORT` not defined.  `dbpath` not defined.  If I fix those, client prints nothing and exits, because as I said before, the thread starts as a daemon and the main thread immediately exits, killing it.  If I remove the thread and just call `recv`, it works, even if I comment out the close on the server side.  Provide a reproducible problem.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm sorry for the poorly formulated question, this edit probably made it cleaner. added images and a .blend of the client, also updated the code and tested it, still getting the same problem. If the deamon where the problem as you suggest, then why I'm I reciving the data upon exit?

Comment: The example still doesn't reproduce your issue.  The server didn't need to switch to a thread and a `while 1: pass`.  Just call StartTcpSocket().  That function has a `while 1` loop in it that spins off a thread for each connection.  That is fine.  The client as written now declares two functions but never calls them.  Really all you need for a client to test it is a flat script that opens the socket, connects, and calls recv(6).  The bytes get received in that scenario.

Comment: @MarkTolonen it does reproduce it. To show it of I recorded it. I starting to think that the problem is related more to blender than python. probably how it uses the use gil when the game engine is running.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed a similar phenomenon. It appears that the Python instance doesn't receive any execution cycles from Blender Game Engine (BGE) unless a controller gets invoked.

A simple solution is:

- Add another Always sensor that is fired on every logic tick.
- Add another Python controller that does nothing, a no-op.
- Hook the sensor to the controller.

I applied this to your .blend as shown in the following screen capture.

[image: screen capture showing added sensor and code]

I tested it by running your server and it seems to work OK.

Cheers, Jim